# Flutter: Dart FFI can't find symbol

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-ffi

I have included `libavcodec.dylib` in a Flutter project following the standard [Flutter FFI instructions](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/c-interop#ios-and-macos).

Calling `DynamicLibrary.open('libavcodec.59.dylib')` executes without issue, and returns a non-negative handle address, which (I think) indicates a successful load.

When I try to lookup any symbol, Flutter throws an error:

> "[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Failed to lookup symbol...".

When I call `providesSymbol()` with various symbol names, it always returns `false`.

**Does anyone know why this might be happening? Are there additional steps needed to bootstrap such a library? how I can debug the root cause of the issue?**

I think this is the [root header file](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavcodec/avcodec.h). This is the lib's [documentation](https://libav.org/documentation/).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the names in the dylib don't quite match the names in the C code. When I lookup the symbols by the names in the dylib, they resolve as expected.

The tool that I used to figure this out was the following:

```
nm -gU mylib.dylib
```